# random.randint() works when printing but not when assigning to a value

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a minesweeper game as a practice project but I have ran into an error when generating the random coordinates for the bombs. Basically, when I run the random.randint() function, it gives me an error when I try to assign it, but not when I print it out.

```
import random
def assignBombs(grid, k):
    m = len(grid) - 1
    n = len(grid[1]) - 1
    while k > 0:
        i = random.randint(0, m)
        j = random.randint(0, n)
        if grid[i][j].bomb == False:
            grid[i][j].bomb == True
            n -= 1
    return grid
grid = initialize(5, 5)
grid = assignBombs(grid, 4)
```

The initialize function will make a 5x5 grid of Cells, a class which has the boolean self.bomb. Please let me know if I need to provide this.

Anyway, this will give me the following error when running:

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

However, if I replace the while loop in the function with a simple print statement:

```
def assignBombs(grid, k):
    m = len(grid) - 1
    n = len(grid[1]) - 1
    print(m, n, random.randint(0, n), random.randint(0, m))
```

This will print out just fine:

```
4 4 3 4
```

Where m and n are the max row and column indices. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `n -= 1` decreases `n` in the loop, so that eventually `random.randint(0, n)` ends up as `randint(0, 0)`, which is the error. You probably want to decrease *`k`*?!

Comment: I guess you want `for _ in range(k)` and then loop the random part until it passes the condition, in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Omg I didn't realize I was still decreasing n... sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not change `k` inside the loop, so it won't stop looping, decreasing `n` and eventually making it 0.

Comment: Omg I didn't realize I was still decreasing n... sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help